# Does Bezout' lemma imply the following?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $y,t$ be relatively prime nonzero integers.

Then as per Bezout's lemma, there are infinitely many integers $a,b$ such that
$$at+by=1$$
Let $x$ be an arbitrary positive integer. Then we have
$$t(ax+yk )+y(bx-tk   )=x$$ where $k$ is arbitrary.

Given the infinitely many choices of $a,b$ and $k$, it is always possible to find a pair $(b,k)$ such that
$$bx-tk=   \gcd(x,t)$$
If so, how can it be proved?

Comment: Given one solution $at + by = 1$ all solutions are of the form $(a+k y) t + (b - k t) y$ - one choice of $(a ,b)$ is enough to generate all solutions

Comment: Please elaborate. I am not sure whether that answers my question.

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but I'm only pointing out that you have one degree of freedom in solutions - $k$, and not the three $a, b, k$

Comment: That's a fair answer. I am not sure how make the question any clearer.

Comment: recommend doing your own tests with some easy computer language.  Possibly you could disprove your own conjecture; regardless, the process would guide you to making an understandable question.

Comment: @WillJagy, would your answer be any different if my statement was it is always possible to find $b,k$ such that the quantity $bx-tk=prime$